# uitextfield input on NSmutablearray

Tags: iphone, ios, nsmutablearray, uitextfield

Im having 8 `UITextFields`,i want to store each textfields input value in `NSMutableArray` ?Can anyone help me to code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will be beneficial to you if you store all values in dictionary format.

Still if you want to store in NSMutableArray then you can do like this :

```
 - (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
 {
      [mutArray addObject:textField.text];
 }
```

Comment: Please take a look before submit your answer [mutArray addObject:textField.text];

Comment: By the way , we can use the default textfield name that we have given in their IBOutlets.So my answer was correct.Still i've edited it.

Comment: But give your answer according to question *i want to store each textfields input value in NSMutableArray*

Comment: Every time the textfield ends editing this method will be called and every time the text will be saved in array.I just missed to make the letter capital.That's it.

Comment: In this way better to store in dictionary where key is textfield and value is text property

Comment: you are using txtField.... and textFieldDidEndEditing have textField...  now can you please tell me how your code is working...is  look at your code..you will get your mistake about txt and text..

Comment: @iUser.. now say where i am wrong..and where is my code is copy Paste..?? why -1

Answer (score 1):

Why not you can try connecting those textfields into an outlet connection like below so that you can keep track of those textfield values where ever you want?

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UITextField) NSArray *textFieldApp;
```

Answer (score 0):

In case if You need only save one time :

```
NSMutableArray *fieldValues = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
             textfield1.text, 
             textfield2.text,
             textfield3.text, 
             textfield4.text, 
             textfield5.text, 
             textfield6.text, 
             textfield7.text, 
             textfield8.text, nil];
```

In case if you need save many times, best solution is using NSMutableDictionary (use tag as key):

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [dict setObject:txtfield.text forKey:textField.tag];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use setValue for key in NSMutableArray

```
NSMutableArray *testArray = [NSMutableArray array];
[testArray setValue:textFiled1InputString forKey:@"field1"];
```

or if you want to use index then use:

```
-insertObject:atIndex: and replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:.
```

of NSMutableArray

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that all text fields are tagged and use this code

```
- (void)store {

    NSMutableArray *arr = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (int i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
        UITextField *tf = (UITextField *)[self.view viewWithTag:i];
        if (tf && [tf isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]] && tf.text.length > 0) {
            [arr addObject:tf.text];
        } else {
            [arr addObject:@"empty"];
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"All values : %@", arr);
}
```